# Is it safe to reinterpret_cast LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS to LPRECT when intercepting WM_NCCALCSIZE?

Tags: c++, winapi

Though it worked for me without problems, but I am afraid that it will explode in my face some day in the future,

```
LPRECT pRect = reinterpret_cast<LPRECT>(lParam);
```

I need to know if it is safe to reinterpret_cast `LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` to `LPRECT` when intercepting `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, if I need to deal with only `(LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)lParam->rgrc[0]` or `(LPARAM)lParam` no matter of the rest of `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` will be!

Refs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-nccalcsize_params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory address of an object is the same as the memory address of its 1st data member. And the memory address of an array is the same as the memory address of its 1st element.

Per the [`WM_NCCALCSIZE` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize):

> lParam
>
> **If wParam is TRUE, lParam points to an NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS structure** that contains information an application can use to calculate the new size and position of the client rectangle.
>
> **If wParam is FALSE, lParam points to a RECT structure**. On entry, the structure contains the proposed window rectangle for the window. On exit, the structure should contain the screen coordinates of the corresponding window client area.

Since the 1st data member of [`NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-nccalcsize_params) is a `RECT[3]` array:

```
typedef struct tagNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS {
  RECT       rgrc[3];
  PWINDOWPOS lppos;
} NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS, *LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS;
```

Then *logically*, there will always be a `RECT` located at the memory address pointed at by the `lParam`, yes.

But *technically*, under C++, what you are proposing is a Strict Alias Violation when `wParam` is `TRUE`, since the `lParam` will be pointing at a `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS`, not a `RECT`.  Per [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object):

> ### Strict aliasing
>
> Given an object with effective type T1, using an lvalue expression (typically, dereferencing a pointer) of a different type T2 is undefined behavior, unless:
>
> - T2 and T1 are compatible types.
> - T2 is cvr-qualified version of a type that is compatible with T1.
> - T2 is a signed or unsigned version of a type that is compatible with T1.
> - T2 is an aggregate type or union type type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union).
> - T2 is a character type (char, signed char, or unsigned char).

Your proposal to access a `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` as if it were a `RECT` does not satisfy those requirements.

But, since the Win32 API is primarily designed for C not C++, your proposal will *likely* "work" in most C++ compilers.

But, to be on the safe side, you really should cast `lParam` to the correct type based on the value of `wParam`, eg:

```
LPRECT pRect;
if (wParam) {
    pRect = &(reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam)->rgrc[0]);
    // or:
    // pRect = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lParam)->rgrc;
}
else {
    pRect = reinterpret_cast<LPRECT>(lParam);
}
```

Comment: I guess I will go the safe way than the fancy one then, but I have one more question; Is this still correct : `pRect = reinterpret_cast<LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS>(lParam)->rgrc;` or not when `wParam` is `TRUE` instead of the code you wrote ?

Comment: Doesn't the fourth exception apply here, making the cast valid without violating the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: The wording of that fourth exception seems inaccurate; for a struct (which can be an aggregate type), it would have to be the first member, not just "among its members".

Comment: That's what I thought too in the first place, the 4th exception apply here for my example.

Comment: @Tomay "*Is this still correct ... or not when `wParam` is `TRUE`*" - yes, that will work, since an array decays into a pointer to the 1st element.

Comment: @Tomay the wording of the 4th exception talks about accessing an object of type `T1` using a dereferenced pointer of type `T2*`, where `T2` needs to contain `T1` as a member. But in this case, `T1` is `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` and `T2` is `RECT`, and `RECT` does not contain a `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` as a member.

Comment: @IInspectable / RemyLebeau The quoted strict aliasing rules are for C, not C++. In C++ aliasing rules apply only to scalar types, but using the cast result would be undefined behavior still since the `RECT` object is not pointer-interconvertible with the `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` object. However, it seems that `*reinterpret_cast<RECT(*)[3]>(lParam)` followed by array-to-pointer decay would be allowed, since the first non-static data member of a standard-layout class object is pointer-interconvertible with it. But that doesn't help avoiding the `if` cases here.